# remove dynamically created div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

It seems to be simple logic thing, but some how I cannot figure it out. I am behind this more than 2 hours and nothing seems to be working..
I am doing a form validation. On submit of the form, I check if the fields are empty or not. If empty, I add a class to the field so it becomes red in color and then create a new div and display a error message. I am having couple of issues with this. I am testing in IE8 and addClass is not working in that.
Below is the code snippet

```
var first =  true;
if(first == true){
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid #FF0004");
        //$(this).addClass("highlight");
        $(this).after('<div class="error_text">Required</div>');
        first = false;
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
}
else{
  $('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid #FF0004");
        //$(this).addClass("highlight");
                  //I ned to remove the Required text here or else it will get added twice.
        $(this).after('');
                  //Add the text here
                    $(this).after('<div class="error_text">Required</div>');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
}
```

So when the user clicks the submit button for first time first = true, it validates and which ever field is empty, it will display that red border and the text as well. This is working fine.
Now when the user fills in some fields and again enter submit, there are some more mandatory fields that are not filled in. So now I want the filled fields to be remove the border and the Required text and then display red and Required for those that are empty now.
I tried so many things and I am sick with this. Somehow I am not getting a right logic for this. 
Can some body out there help me in this? I don't want to use validate plugin.

Comment: why you write `return = false;` correct code is `return false;` or `return true;`...`return = false;` this line means you are assigning false value to return variable.

Comment: if there are errors return false;

Comment: genral note: since you cache the `$(this)` to the variable `input` why do you keep using `$(this)` ?

Answer (score 1):

When present the `<div>` you want to remove is the next element after the one you're checking (the one `this` refers to), so you should be able to just do this to remove it:

```
$(this).next('div.error_text').remove();
```

As an aside, if you want to return a value from your function it should just be `return true` or `return false`, using the equals sign (`=`) is incorrect.

The `first` logic seems unnecessary, since jQuery is good at handling the case where elements don't exist. You could simplify your entire code down to this:

```
var returnValue = true;
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.next('div.error_text').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (input.is(':empty')) {
        input.addClass('highlight');
        input.after('<div class="error_text">Required</div>');
        returnValue = false;
    }
});
return returnValue;
```

Then the following CSS for the `highlight` class:

```
.highlight {
    border: 1px solid #ff0004;
}
```

Note that in the above I've used a `returnValue` variable. That's because you have an anonymous function being passed to `.each()`, and calling `return false` inside that will only end execution of the loop, it won't prevent your form from being submitted.

Comment: oh yea..that was a typo..thanks for pointing out that. I have corrected it.

Comment: Hi Anthony.. yes..I think the above portion of the code posted by you will implement the full logic and submitting the form and checking for empty fields. and displaying the error message if the form is resubmitted also. Am I correct?  Also a note..when I use addClass, it was not giving the border and color..I m using IE8

Comment: I tried input.addClass('highlight'); But that is nor giving border red. But if I use input.css("border","1px solid #FF0004"); it works..Is it the problem with IE8?

Comment: Even after using the above code, when I resubmit the form, the error text keeps on adding..It is not removing the div "Required"

Comment: @user1049057 I made a mistake, I was trying to select an element with class `text_error` but it should instead be `error_text` - edited the answer to fix that. Try making that change and then trying again?

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried that..but still input.addClass('highlight');is not working. When I use $(this).css("border","1px solid #FF0004"); its working

Comment: @user1049057 It's possible IE8 doesn't handle it correctly, in that case just use the `.css()` method instead. Does removing the "Required" element work if you change the class name in the selector to the correct one?

Comment: No.removeClass and remove the "required text" also does not work ..So for adding red box I can use $(this).css("border","1px solid #FF0004");input.after('<divclass="error_text">Required</div>');  But for removing the red box and text, I cannot use  css("border",""); as it will remove all the previous already existing also. So any idea how to handle the remove css for border and "Required text"

Comment: @user1049057 Try changing the CSS declaration to: `.highlight {border: 1px solid #ff0004 !important;}` and see if that works? There may be another CSS declaration that's being applied instead of your highlight. Not sure why removing the Required text isn't working, can you post the starting HTML for that section of the page in the question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39067/discussion-between-user1049057-and-anthony-grist)